# iOptron ZEQ25GT mount advice needed

Tags: photography

I am interested in purchasing a used iOptron ZEQ25GT mount which is a being sold at $500 by an experienced owner. It is in good condition. Can someone share their experience on using this mount, or any other insights? This will be my first EQ mount after having used star trackers and will be using it for astrophotography. Any information is much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.skyatnightmagazine.com/reviews/mounts/ioptron-zeq25-gt-equatorial-mount/